# How to store a pointer to "pick up where you left off" while iterating in a spark scala dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say I have some dataframe that I'm reading in, and each time I want to display the top 2 rows as per a sorted column. The next time I read in that dataframe, I don't want to start at the beginning, but rather display the next 2 rows from where I left off the previous time. I'm thinking I'll need to create some binary pointer column that tells it where to start/stop, and when it reaches the end it should go back to the beginning. Here is an example:

```
  var df = Seq(("Mike",1),("Kevin",2),("Bob",3),("Steve",4),("Dave",5),("Dustin",6),("Melvin",7),("Henry",8)).toDF("name","score")
```

[image]

on the first run through, the output should be the first two rows Mike and Kevin:

[image]

on the second run through, the output should be the next two rows,

[image]

and so on and so forth.

How would I do this dynamically so that when I read in the CSV it can automatically figure out what to display? Thinking I'd have to initialize a "pointer" column and then somehow loop through it and overwrite the existing file each time with the new pointer location. How would you go about that?

I started it off with this code but ideally I need to have a 1 in the first row when I initialize instead of all zeros

```
df.withColumn("pointer",lit(0)).show
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the dataframe as CSV after every read and emitting top 2 rows then you can add a discriminator column in there ( I believe you used pointer in that sense) and save it in the dataframe ( ultimately in CSV as well).
When you read the CSV back into dataframe, you can filter the rows that have this flag set. This will help you get rid of those rows which you already have outputted.